# Iphone App: How to fill an image with empty areas with coregraphics?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, core-graphics

I'm a beginner developing apps for Iphone and was wondering if is possible to do the following:

I have an image .png wich is a simple draw of a figure bounded with black edges and empty areas. I wonder if there is a method or a mode to fill the closed empty areas of the image.

Its like as the pot of MSpaint filling.

I have this code:

```
CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 15), image.CGImage);
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 145, 15)];
```

Now i don't know what to do to fill...

I'll be very grateful if someone can answer this question. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're drawing the image twice. There's no need to do that. Either send the UIImage a `drawInRect:` message or call `CGContextDrawImage` and pass the CGImage; don't do both. You probably should (only) be telling the UIImage object to draw, since the CGImage may draw upside-down.

Answer (score 0):

> I have an image … wich is … bounded with black edges and empty areas.

If by “empty” you mean these areas have alpha zero, simply fill the context with the desired color (filling the entire extent of the context) first, then draw the image on top. The color will show through where the image is transparent, and not where it isn't.

A closer match to what you asked for would be to draw the image using the Copy blend mode, then do the color fill using the Source Out blend mode.

[Blend modes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html%23//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetBlendMode) are your friend; learn them well, because you can do a lot with them.

Comment: Right, the empty areas are transparent (or alpha 0). I have an idea of what you mean, but this does all parts transparent? 

Imagine a boy drawn, I would like for example fill the head with one color, the body with another color ... if this is the method to be followed at least I know where to go.

Thank you very much for your response! Although an example if is not very complicated would help me a lot!

Comment: Yes, it does all transparent portions. If you want the user to be able to flood-fill specific portions, you'll have to implement the fill by doing that on a pixel buffer yourself. Andy Finnell wrote a good post about the algorithm behind a flood fill: http://losingfight.com/blog/2007/08/28/how-to-implement-a-magic-wand-tool/

Comment: @karse:I want to do the same coloring Application.My Task is,i want to choose any color among no.of colors and click on the image that particular part want to get coloring.The remaining part as same as before.Please help me in this regard.Thank You

Comment: @ iphonecool, I tried to do the following but without much success. make a recursive function from the point where you touch the screen and draw pixels around the 4 directions until find the black color of the border to stop. It worked, but if the areas were large the algorithm could take about 5 or more seconds. Noting other applications that did the fill, I discovered that they make the fill painting layers, I guess painting the UIViews background but I'm not sure how they do that. I wish you good luck and if you got it share the solution with us!