# Detect blank areas in an image

Tags: iphone

[image: This is a sample image i use in my app]

I Have an image in which there are some blank areas.What i want is that when the user touches these blank areas a pop up should come asking the user to select an image that can be added to that area.I have done this by just adding a button in the background of the blank area.That worked for a few images.Since the position of the blank area varies for each image that is not a good idea to follow.So is there any provision in ios to detect blank areas and thus make them act like a button. In the image you can see the text "Place your image here".
I want that area to work somewhat like a button.any help

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921548/iphone-app-how-to-fill-an-image-with-empty-areas-with-coregraphics)

Answer (score -1):

You will need to have some metadata associated with each image. The data will tell you where to put each button. I doubt you can find some code to automatically detect where to put the buttons.

Comment: Btw, if you wanna fight: this is extremely inefficient and not portable -- if you have a new image, you have to manually recreate the metadata.